# How to change the icon for a specific MSC file?

Tags: windows, icons, shortcuts

Many years ago (in the early XP days), I created several Management Console files (i.e. .MSC) for different functions (i.e. AD Users and Computers, Group Policy, etc.).  To distinguish them, I made shortcuts and assigned "cool", custom icons to the shortcuts.

Over the years, I have brought those MSC files from computer to computer because they are setup as I need/want and there was no need to recreate them.  At some point, somehow, the actual .MSC files have acquired the icon I originally assigned to the shortcut.  **Each .MSC file has a unique icon**, and I can copy just that .MSC file to other computers and they display the custom icon.

I can make shortcuts to the .MSC file and the shortcut has the custom icon.  If I attempt to change an icon for other shortcuts, and go to "open" the .MSC file to use its icon, I cannot. ("The file contains no icons.")

I assume I must have done (and forgotten) something special to have this "feature" that according to everything I read should not be possible.  Any ideas on how I could have given a file an individual custom icon and/or how can I change the icon if I want to?

Thanks.

Comment: I have no such problem on Windows 10 20H2.  The files are simple xml so you can poke around in there.  I just used MMC to make a custom console, add snap-ins, and assign an icon.  Not only does my xml reference where I got the icon from, it embedded the entire icon as base64 under a binary section toward the bottom of the file.

Comment: Oh.. and I too used so many useful features from XP that are now gone.

Comment: Ah!  "Change Icon" is an item in "Options" when you create a new MSC.  If the Console mode is changed to limited access and it's blocked from saving changes, the icon can't be changed later (except possibly in the XML).

Comment: I bet that second tiny binary chunk at the bottom of the file is some sort of CRC that matches the file itself. :)  Glad you found your solution.